# How to render a jsp file of different CSS and images spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC Application. According to the requirement i have 35 categories and all the categories pages will have same structure but differ with different colors and images and all of them were called with different url.

eg:

cat1.html 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYl1Amc-L0YR0RrXy05cWFmSFE/view?usp=sharing

cat2.html
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYl1Amc-L0YZnh2b2ZpT19md2c/view?usp=sharing

My Mam suggests to create different JSP files for all categories. But I feel it will be better to render it dynamically with single JSP file.

Can we do that way?

I tried of using rest request /{cat}.html and matching it to load different CSS & Image files to model like this, but didn't worked.

```
@Controller
```

public class ViewController {

```
List<UI> uiList = new ArrayList<UI>();

@RequestMapping(value = "/{cat}.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String article(@PathVariable("cat") String cat, ModelMap model,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    UI cat1 = new UI();
    cat1.setId(1);
    cat1.setCatCssFile("app-cat1.css");
    cat1.setCalendarImage("pic1.png");
    cat1.setCat("cat1");
    uiList.add(cat1);

    UI cat2 = new UI();
    cat2.setId(2);
    cat2.setCatCssFile("app-cat2.css");
    cat2.setCat("cat2");
    cat2.setCalendarImage("pic2.png");
    uiList.add(cat2);


    for (UI ui : uiList) {
        if (ui.getCat().equals(cat)) {
            model.addAttribute("ui", ui);
        }
    }

    return "article";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are near of the best solution, i would do something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{cat}.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String article(@PathVariable("cat") String cat, ModelMap model,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
        //code
        model.addAttribute("cat", cat);
        return "article"
}
```

And in your HTML file (The notation i used its from thymeleaf, you should use the JSP option to render controller variables)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{'/app/css/' + ${cat} + '.css'}" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know Thymleaf . I will try it now. Can't  we do without Thymeleaf?

Comment: Sure. YOu could use this in a normal JSP <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles-${category}.css"> and will read the category value from the controller model